# Ajax executando condições IF e ELSE simultaneamente

Tags: javascript, ajax, condição

Fala galerinha, estou tendo alguns problemas com uma Ajax Request em Javascript Vanilla, onde ao enviar a requisição, tanto o código dentro do IF como dentro do ELSE são executados simultâneamente. Dei uma boa pesquisada e tentei debugar, mas infelizmente o comportamento se mantém.

```js
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("alert").classList.add("alert-success");
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "Usuário registrado com sucesso!";
    document.getElementById("alert").classList.remove("d-none");

    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("alert").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("alert").classList.remove("alert-success");
    }, 5000)
}else{
    document.getElementById("alert").classList.add("alert-danger");
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    document.getElementById("alert").classList.remove("d-none");

    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("alert").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("alert").classList.remove("alert-danger");
    }, 5000)
};

}

xhttp.open("POST", "register.php", true);
xhttp.send(`email=${inputEls[0].value}&user=${inputEls[1].value}&fullname=${inputEls[2]}&password=${inputEls[3].value}`);
```

Gostaria de entender o por que de esse comportamento estar rolando, e como posso resolvê-lo, mas não consegui encontrar nas docs da MDN ou em outros lugares.

Answer (score 0):

Após algumas horas a mais de pesquisa, me toquei sobre a propriedade `readyState` e como eu estava comparando ele no meu IF, e que todas as vezes que o readyState mudava (de 0 à 3) ele executava a condição do else, e ao fim, dando um `200 - OK` ele entraria no IF, podendo tudo isso ocorrer em menos de um segundo, isso acumulava as classes, sendo assim, o trecho abaixo, deveria ser alterado

```js
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    //Code
}else{
    //Code
};
```

Utilizando como base a referência da própria w3schools, e a MDN, pude entender melhor sobre o erro que estava ocorrendo, então adicionei mais uma condicional de validação, ao mover o `this.readyState == 4` para fora da condicional anterior, ficando assim:

```js
if(this.readyState == 4){
  if(this.status == 200){
    //Code
  }else{
    //Code
  };
};
```

Isso bastou para resolver o problema na requisição.

Refs.:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState